# Pandas assigning values to dataframe, conditional on values in another with the same dimensions issue/question

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to better understand Pandas/Python so I've been playing around with some stuff. I ran into an issue, I know some workarounds, but I'm wondering why it happened in the first place.

Here's my full code, followed by an explanation:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 10).round(2), index = list(range(1,6)), columns = list(range(1, 11)) )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = range(df1.shape[0]), columns = range(df1.shape[1]) )

df2[df1.iloc[:]>0.6] = 1
df2[df1.iloc[:]<0.6] = 0
```

I create, 2 dataframes. The first with random numbers, the second dataframe is empty but has the same dimensions as the first. Based on the values in the first dataframe, I'd like to modify the values in the second.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 10), index = list(range(1,6)), columns = list(range(1, 11)) )
```

My first datframe I create looks like this:

```
df1

      1      2       3        4      5        6      7       8        9     10
1   0.24    0.03    0.93    0.38    0.03    0.83    0.47    0.85    0.79    0.65
2   0.66    0.25    0.01    0.28    0.19    0.26    0.25    0.48    0.33    0.92
3   0.53    0.33    0.78    0.04    0.36    0.63    0.16    0.16    0.21    0.96
4   0.76    0.03    0.89    0.15    0.24    0.90    0.59    0.41    0.92    0.98
5   0.72    0.45    0.95    0.44    0.79    0.93    0.90    0.48    0.61    0.02
```

I create a second dataframe based on the dimensions of the second:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = range(df1.shape[0]), columns = range(df1.shape[1]) )
```

What I would like to do now, is say that for values that are greater 0.6 in df1, I would like the corresponding value in df2 to be 1. And for values less than 0.6 I would like the values to be 0.

I did that in the following way, by slicing df1 and then using that slice on df2, and then assigning the values.

```
df2[df1.loc[:]>0.6] = 1
df2[df1.loc[:]<0.6] = 0
```

I thought this would work, but instead, the first row and first column are still NANs

```
df2

         0   1   2   3   4  5   6   7   8   9
 0      NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 1      NaN  0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1
 2      NaN  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 3      NaN  0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0
 4      NaN  1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

Now the reason this didn't work, I think, is because the column names and the row names don't align between the two indices, but what I'm trying to understand is why that's happening.

I thought when I sliced df1 based on the conditional it created an array  of trues/falses, that I could use on any other dataframe with the same dimension:

```
[df1.loc[:]>0.6]
```

r

```
       1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10
  1  False  False   True  False  False   True  False   True   True   True
  2   True  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   True
  3  False  False   True  False  False   True  False  False  False   True
  4   True  False   True  False  False   True  False  False   True   True
  5   True  False   True  False   True   True   True  False   True  False
```

I thought that mapping of trues and falses above could be used anywhere, it seems like it can't. Is there a way around this doesn't involve renaming the columns/rows to match between the 2 dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)  # for reproducibility
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 10), index = list(range(1,6)), columns = list(range(1, 11)))
df2 = df1 > 0.6
print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10
1  False   True   True  False  False  False  False   True   True   True
2  False   True   True  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
3   True  False  False  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
4   True  False  False   True   True   True  False  False   True  False
5  False  False  False   True  False   True  False  False  False  False
```

If need the output to be integer:

```
df2 = (df1 > 0.6).astype(int)
print(df2)
```

**Output** *(integer)*

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
2   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
4   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
5   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

If need to map to values to True and False, use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df2 = (df1 > 0.6)
df2[:] = np.where(df2, 'M', 'F')
print(df2)
```

**Output** (*where*)

```
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
1  F  M  M  F  F  F  F  M  M  M
2  F  M  M  F  F  F  F  F  F  F
3  M  F  F  F  F  M  F  F  F  F
4  M  F  F  M  M  M  F  F  M  F
5  F  F  F  M  F  M  F  F  F  F
```

Comment: Well crud, that does seem to get me close. If you don't mind, I have a few follow up questions. When I do that, df2 turns into trues and falses, any way to convert that into 0s and 1s, or any other 2 values? Also, the thing I really want to understand, why does the slicing way I tried, depend on the name of the columns and rows? Is there a way to just create a generic array of trues/falses that can be applied to any dataframe without respect to the name of the rows or columns?

Comment: "Pandas aligns all AXES when setting Series and DataFrame from .loc, and .iloc." 
Indexing a dataframe with the [] operator will utilize any index available. The dataframes in your examples have different indices so here it works like an SQL outer join.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: @MSCRN Updated the answer with examples for your questions. I don't understand: Also, the thing I really want to understand, why does the slicing way I tried, depend on the name of the columns and rows? Is there a way to just create a generic array of trues/falses that can be applied to any dataframe without respect to the name of the rows or columns?

Comment: @skuzzy I think I follow, though I'm not sure about the SQL outer join bit. So if I understand, if you're using, .loc, .iloc, or the [] operator, Pandas first looks to match the axes (columns and rows) based on their names, and not on position?

Comment: Position can have many meanings. How do you determine position in a dataframe that can have many levels/tiers? What you are thinking of are relative coordinates. Indices are sort of absolute coordinates.
As an example, take students from two universities. Is the first-rank in university 1 equivalent to first-rank in university 2?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `np.where`, notice here is open bin, which means value equal to 0.6 will return `NaN`

```
df2[:] = np.where(df1>0.6,1,0)
df2
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1
3  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0
4  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0
```

Comment: This is incredibly elegant, thank you. I wasn't aware of that numpy function or that you could use it on pandas frame like that.